# Cocos2dx - how to update screen only when necessary

Tags: android, cocos2d-x

Cocos2dx updates screen in a loop no matter if there is something new to draw or not.
Even if I have one sprite which is not animated, the opengl renderer is called and screen is repaited at 60 fps - so phone battery is discharged quite fast.

Is it possible to redraw screen only when necessary (for example when sprite is animated)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not really. You could hack the engine to not clear the framebuffer if none of the nodes return a "status changed" flag.

However all game engines draw everything every frame - even still images. There's nothing won by not redrawing, except perhaps a little battery. There's however potential for glitches if the "changed" state isn't updated properly, plus there will be an added and unnecessary overhead of checking for the changed status.

Therefore: it's theoretically possible, it's just not sensible to do so.

You could reduce the framerate (temporarily or altogether via director animationInterval) or pause the director to conserve energy while your game isn't updating, though this will introduce input lag. The alternative is to implement the game in the native UI framework, especially if your game is mostly idle anyway.